# Writing a powershell array object to a single cell in an excel sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

I have a powershell variable of type array defined as`$a = ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")`. I want to write all the contents of `$a` to a single cell in an excel sheet.
These are what I have tried so far:-
(i) `$sheet.cells.Item(5,5) = $a` - Prints only the first value i.e. 1 to the cell.
(ii)`$sheet.cells.Item(5,5) = "$a"` - Prints the output in a horizontal format like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` in a single cell(E5) where as I want the output to be like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

(iii) `foreach ($i in $a){
$sheet.cells.Item(5,5) = $a[$i]}` - Doesn't return anything on the excel sheet.

Is there a way in powershell by which I can achieve the desired output?

Comment: `$a -join "\`r\`n"`

Comment: This just did the trick for me. Thanks 4c74356b41.